# Why does XMLStarlet return additional whitespace/newline for XML text nodes?

Tags: command-line, xml

I'm trying to manipulate XML data with [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) for translation purposes as asked in https://superuser.com/questions/598910/translate-text-nodes-of-graphml-xml-cas but although the nodes I am trying to read are returned, there is whitespace/newlines returned.
Sample XML can be found in the other question and the program call is as follows:

```
xml sel --noblanks --text --template --nl --value-of "//y:NodeLabel" --value-of "//y:EdgeLabel" my.graphml
```

resulting in

```
...
The node's text
...
          The edge's text
...
```

(`...` represents a blank line)

I would like an explanation of what is happening and whether the result is to be expected or if this is caused by XMLStarlet. A fixed program call would be appreciated, but of course alternative programs or - if neccessary - filtering the blank lines would be acceptable as well (grep/sed/awk, CMD).

Answer (score 3):

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -v "//node/item" file.xml
```

and it outputs the content of

```
<node><item>content</item></node>
```

as text without additional whitespace.

Comment: I see that the OP specifically asked about XMLStarlet. For the benefit of people who find their way here with a web search that did _not_ include xmlstarlet, there's an alternative solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11777638/785213 which _might_ work if you have to use something else, like `xmllint`.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know but I solved the task with [Python](http://python.org/) and [lxml](http://lxml.de/), which does not capture whitespace in a node's `text` member.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you added `--nl` to your command. From the [docs](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.txt):

> -n or --nl               - print new line

That is going to add a newline to each element that is printed.

Comment: Thanks for your input, however, as the original question is quite old and I did solve the task differently then, I am not going to test your suggestion - but feel free to add the correct command and its output, as it might help others.